# if F is closed in $\mathbb R$, then F is compact. proof problem

Tags: real-analysis

F$\subseteq$K$\subseteq$ $\mathbb R$ and K is compact.

prove that if F is closed in $\mathbb R$, then F is compact.
(no use the heine-borel thm)

i don't think how to solve this problem.

Comment: What is your definition of compact ?

Answer (score 2):

This is true in a general topological space.

We can directly check the definition of compact set. Indeed, suppose that $\{O_i\}$ is an open covering of $F$. In addition, since $F$ is closed, we have that $O:=F^c$ is open.

Moreover $\{O,O_i\}$ is an open covering of $K$. Therefore, we can extract a finite subcovering $O,O_{i_1},\cdots,O_{i_n}$ of $K$.

Neccessarily, $O_{i_1},\cdots,O_{i_n}$ is a covering of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X:=\mathbb{R}$. Let $I$ be an indexing set and $\Lambda=\{V_{\alpha}\mid\alpha\in I\}$ be an arbitrary open cover for $F$. Since $X\setminus F$ is open, it follows that $\Lambda$ together with $X\setminus F$ is an open cover for $K$. Thus, $K$ can be covered by a finite number of sets, say, $V_{1},\ldots,V_{N}$ from $\Lambda$ together with possibly $X\setminus F$. Since $F \subseteq K$, $V_{1},\ldots,V_{N}$ cover $F$, and it follows that $F$ is compact.

Note that the statement is true more generally in any topological space $X$, we didn't use the fact that the overlying space is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Thanks, I have changed the notation now.